# photo realistic sss skin shader... i need a great node setup

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

So i was looking for a great node setup, heres my results so far and my node setup. I was wondering what i was doing wrong because it doesn't look good, also i know light setup is important but for right now i want to focus on the nodes than play around with different lighting angles.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Scrapbook for skin. Collections of nodes for realistic skin with pores. You might find something after page 7 or 8. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13-D6Y6u8yJ4mbcBAp6-lmsaie3s9psxlexm2yBkqLEQ/mobilepresent?slide=id.g14f82c173dcbf2d2_0

Comment: you should begin by increasing the Roughness value, the material is too glossy, it looks like oil